# Unzip a directory and save it into another directory in Flask

Tags: html, css, flask

Why am I getting an error:  missing one required positional argument (ziph) in flask.
Here is my code

```
@app.route('/ziph',methods=["GET","POST"])
def ziped(ziph):
    path = 'C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/project/extracted_images'
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file))

anotherpath = "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/project/dataset"
os.chdir(anotherpath)
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('dataset.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
ziped(zipf)
zipf.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should add the error as well you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line: `ziped` expects one argument and is receiving none.

Some possible solutions, depending on how the route is called.

If `ziph` is sent as argument (e.g. `http://example.com/ziph/filename`, then the route must accept an argument. You can find the flask doc [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules)

If `ziph` is a GET parameter, then the function need not (should not?) take an argument. Set the value of `ziph` in the function from `request.args`

Comment: Yes ziph is an argument.I changed my route to @app.route('/ziped/<ziph>',methods=["GET","POST"])
 But how to access this route ? When i access my port by writing http://127.0.0.1:5001/ziped . It says URL not found

Comment: If route expects an argument (in this case "ziph"), and none is sent it will return a 404 Not Found.